# Problem with Ninject and MVC3 Dependency injection action filter on Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, action-filter, ninject.web.mvc

Recently I decided to remove a heap of action level filters in a controller and replace them with a single controller level filter.

Now I'm getting this error message.

```
Error activating LogActionFilter
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
 1) Request for LogActionFilter

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for LogActionFilter only once.
```

I'm sure the error is related to action filter being bound twice, as that's what I've changed. However, when I view the documentation [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Conditional-bindings-for-filters) I can see it specifies/does the same. So I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My sample controller

```
[LogAction]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    { 

    }
}
```

My registration code

```
public static void RegisterFilters()
{
    Kernel.BindFilter<LogActionFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
    .WhenControllerHas<LogActionAttribute>();

    Kernel.BindFilter<LogActionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
        .WhenActionMethodHas<LogActionAttribute>();
}
```

Comment: FYI, `BindFilter` is an extension method from the `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax` namespace [per this guy's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc/6193490#6193490)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if your controller and one of its actions have the LogActionAttribute at the same time.

Comment: Hi Remo. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've checked for this situation and found that I don't have the filter to any other actions. I made a quick example site to confirm I can reproduce this. I'll put in on github soon and I'll post a link.

Comment: Hi Remo. If you get a chance [here is the link](https://github.com/pleb/Examples/tree/master/Ninject%20Action%20Controller%20Filter%20Problem/NinjectExample/NinjectExample.Web) to the sample project I threw up on Github

Comment: Ah sorry I was already on the next version. Support for multiple filters has been added to the current development build. You have to update to 2.3 found on the continuous integration server: teamcity.codebetter.com But be aware this is still work in progress. In terms of MVC its pretty much final though but not very well tested.

Comment: Prefect, I'll update to the latest version. I'll help test it ;)

Comment: @Remo, I ran into the same issue with 2.2, so I uninstalled all Ninject Nuget packages from my app. Next, I downloaded 2.3 from TeamCity and referenced all the dlls. When I tried to build, I got an error saying "The type of namespace name 'Bootsrapper' could not be found." `Bootstrapper` is used in `App_Start.NinjectMVC3`, which gets created when you install the Nuget package, but it does not appear to be part of the TeamCity build. How can I work around this problem? Better yet, would you consider releasing a Nuget package for 2.3 called "Ninject.MVC3 2.3 Preview"?

Comment: @DanM You need Ninject.Web.Common

Comment: @Remo. Plus one for the 2.3 on NuGet. Any chance of a NuGet product line of Ninject*-NightlyBuild?

Answer (score 3):

(I know the answer's already accepted but this is for the sake of documentation.)

In case you can only use the release version, a temporary solution is to create two subclasses and register them separately. Here's an example from my application:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
   /* call base ctor */
}

public class MyControllerAuthorizationFilter : MyAuthorizationFilter
{
   /* call base ctor */
}

public class MyActionAuthorizationFilter : MyAuthorizationFilter
{
}
```

Then setup filter bindings:

```
this.BindFilter<MyControllerAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerHas<MyAttribute>()
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<ProtectedAttribute>(/*...*/) ;

this.BindFilter<MyActionAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
            .WhenActionMethodHas<MyAttribute>()
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<ProtectedAttribute>(/*...*/) ;
```

Make sure to call the correct 'WithConstructorArgumentFrom[**Controller/Action**]Attribute method or you'll get a 'Sequence has no elements' error (I did).

Answer (score 1):

Better workaround. In fact I use this in the new version too rather than have two bindings for controllers and actions.

```
this.BindFilter<MyFilter>(FilterScope.Global, int.MinValue)
    .When((controllerContext, actionDescriptor) =>
                                                 controllerContext
                                                .Controller
                                                .GetType()
                                                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute),true)
                                                .Length > 0 
    || actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Length > 0);
```

Comment: Nice one DalSoft. FYI, an easier way of testing for attributes is: Action `actionDecriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Any()` or for controller `actionDecriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Any()`