# Dependency Injection with Ninject and Filter attribute for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm writing a custom Authorization Filter for asp.net mvc 3. I need to inject a userservice into the class but I have no idea how to do this.

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private IUserService userService;
    private string[] roles;

    public AuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm using ninject for dependency injection. I do not want to use a Factory or service locator pattern.

My bindings look like this in the global.acsx:

```
    internal class SiteModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use factory? In that case you have to keep a reference to kernel in your Application class, and manually Get<IUserService>() in controller constructor. In Mvc 3 factory really makes sense as you are overriding the original one. There are ninject nugets for this also.

Comment: Jakubmal, could you make an answer using factories then?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

See this answer: [Custom Authorization MVC 3 and Ninject IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572257/custom-authorization-mvc-3-and-ninject-ioc/5572752#5572752)

If you want to use constructor injection then you need to create an attribute and a filter.

```
/// Marker attribute
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute { }

/// Filter
public class MyAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
      private readonly IUserService _userService;
      public MyAuthorizeFilter(IUserService userService)
      {
          _userService = userService;
      }

      public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
      {
          var validUser = _userService.CheckIsValid();

          if (!validUser)
          {
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "AccessDenied" }, { "controller", "Error" } });
          }
      }
}
```

Binding:

```
this.BindFilter<MyAuthorizeFilter>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<MyAuthorizeAttribute>();
```

Controller:

```
[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
public class YourController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How would you setup the implementation to accomodate: `[MyAuthorizeAttribute("Admin", "Contributer")]`? Passing parameters.

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations

+1 For giving the answer that supports Constructor instead of Property Injection

Comment: @Lol coder - see Remo's link above for how to configure filters.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to setup the attribute constructor to accept both params and the service.

Comment: I read the config... still can't figure out how to get attribute constructor arguments to the filter's constructor arguments... I'm missing something. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305476/ninject-binding-attribute-to-filter-with-constructor-arguments

Comment: @one.beat.consumer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205187/setup-filter-attribute-for-dependency-injection-to-accept-params-in-constructor/6205526#6205526

Comment: @B Z:  Thanks, I did not find that Question when I search yesterday so I opened my own, and found the solution on my own as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305476/ninject-binding-attribute-to-filter-with-constructor-arguments/8306795#8306795 - thanks for your help.

Comment: Did they take out the BindFilter method on a recent version of Ninject? I can't seem to get it to recognize it and suggest a namespacce.

Comment: @kmehta make sure you have Ninject.Web.Mvc referenced

Comment: I have a dumb question. Do I perform the binding in RegisterServices (in NinjectWebCommon.cs)?

Comment: @BZ: What's wrong in Wolfgang solution given below. Taking the instance from current session?

Answer (score 11):

I would *highly* recommend [B Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194159/17242583). **DO NOT use `[Inject]`!**

I used an `[Inject]` like [Darin Dimitrov said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193490/17242583) was possible and it actually caused threading issues under high load, high contention situations in conjunction with `.InRequestScope`.

[B Z's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194159/17242583) is also what is on the Wiki and I have seen many places where [Remo Gloor](https://github.com/remogloor) ([Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject) author) says this is the correct way to do it, e.g. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations.

Downvote `[Inject]` answers in here because seriously you will get burned (probably in production if you don't load test properly beforehand!).

Comment: I did and no one would see it because its hidden by default (too far down). Based on the fact I spent 3 days trying to figure out what went wrong with Darin's answer I figure it is VERY relevant and worthy of an official answer to avoid anyone using it by mistake and getting burned

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple solution for any occasion where construction is not handled by Ninject:

```
var session = (IMyUserService)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IMyUserService));
```

Actually this is exactly what I am using with my custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. Much easier than having to implement a separate `FilterAttribute`.

Answer (score 8):

On way would be to use a property injection and decorate the property with the `[Inject]` attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    [Inject]
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    private string[] roles;
  
    ...
}
```

Constructor injection doesn't work well with attributes as you will no longer be able to decorate controllers/actions with them. You could only use constructor injection with the filter binding syntax in Ninject:

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    private string[] roles;

    public AuthorizeAttribute(IUserService userService, params string[] roles)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
  
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
internal class SiteModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();

        this.BindFilter<AuthorizeAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerType<AdminController>();
    }
}
```

The `BindFilter<>` extension method is defined in the `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax` namespace so make sure you have brought that into scope before calling it on a kernel.

Comment: What if I do not use constructor bindings and used the `[Inject]` attribute, will I be able to decorate the controllers/actions?

Comment: Is there additional code needed when I'm using he `[Inject]` property?

Comment: @Lol coder, no, you just need the `Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();` part.

Comment: Any idea why `UserService` would still be null? I had this same problem with `Providers` too.

Comment: @Lol coder, no idea. Works fine for me. I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application, installed the NInject.MVC3 NuGet package, declared a IUserService inteface and UserService implementation, declared a custom MyAuthorizeAttribute using property injection and used the generated `App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs` to configure the kernel. Then I simply decorated my HomeController with the attribute and the injection worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for specifying the namespace!!! It's annoying to have to find the namespace that you need for extension methods!

Comment: I would highly recommend B Z's answer. DO NOT use [Inject] it can create race conditions under high load!

Comment: +1 for clarifying, "The BindFilter<> extension method is defined in the Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax namespace so make sure you have brought that into scope before calling it on a kernel."  Saved me some time hunting.