# Setup filter attribute for dependency injection to accept params in constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm following a ninject filter attribute setup on this [page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations).

For them, they have:

```
.WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<LogAttribute>(
      "logLevel", attribute => attribute.LogLevel);
```

The second parameter is expecting a `Func<LogAttribute, object> callback`. Their actual param list is setup as follows:

```
Log(LogLevel = Level.Debug)
```

But my filter attribute is setup as follows:

```
public class AuthAttribute : FilterAttribute { }

public class AuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    private readonly IUserService userService;
    private string[] roles;

    //Stuck on the constructor also. How do I accept params?
    public AuthFilter(IUserService userService, params string[] roles)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Somehow this is wrong. Because I want my filter to look like:

```
[Auth("Admin", "Contrib")]
```

My bindings:

```
 kernel.BindFilter<AuthFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerHas<AuthAttribute>()
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<AuthAttribute>("roles", /*Stuck here*/)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make roles into a property in your attribute.

Attribute:

```
public class AuthAttribute : FilterAttribute 
{ 
  public string[] Roles { get; set; }

  public AuthAttribute(params string[] roles)
  {
      this.Roles = roles;
  }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class AuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

  private readonly IUserService userService;
  private readonly string[] roles;

  public AuthFilter(IUserService userService, string[] roles)
  {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.roles = roles;
  }

  public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Controller

```
   [AuthAttribute("a", "b")]
   public class YourController : Controller 
   {

   }
```

Binding:

```
kernel.BindFilter<AuthFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerHas<AuthAttribute>()
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<AuthAttribute>("roles", attribute => attribute.Roles);
```

Comment: So I remove this from the constructor?

Comment: And how do I access it in the `OnAuthorization` method?

Comment: Thanks this works. How do I setup the binding for both controller and action? When I have another binding for actions, it says multiple bindings found.

Comment: @Lol coder...hmm, not sure what the issue could be, the ninject documentation has good examples on how to setup both. Maybe try posting a different question, someone may be able to help more.

Comment: See http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/2547e261a7201333 and 
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/commit/686b1ad3c169b06ef053a1219629625759343880

Comment: @Remo Gloor, So I need to download the nightly build?

Comment: Yes. And you have to use Ninject.Web.Common. See the sample app of MVC about how to setup.

Comment: [+1]  I was having the same problem, and had a mirror question up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305476/ninject-binding-attribute-to-filter-with-constructor-arguments/8306795#8306795 - solved it the same way with Remo's pointer to documentation and a little trial/error with the Func<> signature callback. Thanks BZ and Remo.

Comment: Remo - i'm a bit nervous to use the nightly builds in a production application. you have any guess/rumor when the next stable version will be available to allow dual constructor and action binding? I pulled the package off NuGet and looks like it is 2.2

Comment: Is there a way to do this by inheriting from the `AuthorizeAttribute` rather than from the `FilterAttribute` because it seems to me like I would need to duplicate the majority of the `AuthorizeAttribute` from here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs considering that I just need a way to access the `Roles` property of the Attribute, in the Filter .. while injecting a user service into the Filter too