# What's the best way to protect all actions from a Controller except one (Login)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Currently I have `[Authorize]` attributes on all of the methods on my `AdminController` except for the `Logon` action.

What's the *cleanest* way to invert this, so I don't have to remember to add the attributes to all methods, but rather add an attribute only to the method(s) that should be available without being logged in?

Would I be better just moving the `Logon` action to its own controller, and applying the `[Authorize]` attribute to the AdminController class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 you could implement a custom global [action filter provider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html):

```
public class MyProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var rd = controllerContext.RouteData;
        var controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals("admin", controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals("logon", actionDescriptor.ActionName))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Filter>();
        }

        return new[]
        {
            new Filter(new AuthorizeAttribute(), FilterScope.Action, 0)
        };
    }
}
```

which could be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new MyProvider());
```

Now if you are using some DI container such as NInject for example it supports [filter binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364047/how-to-use-ninject-to-inject-services-into-an-authorization-filter/6364134#6364134) meaning that you could configure the kernel to inject the filter dynamically based on the context.

The pros of this approach is that now nomatter what controller or action is being added to your application => it will require authorization.

Comment: I'd seen something like this, but was hoping there was a "nicer" way, that would survive renaming actions/controllers, etc.

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny, OK, then decorate your LogOn action with some custom attribute (not an action filter, a plain custom CLR attribute) and in the `GetFilters` implementation of the provider look in the `ActionDescriptor` for the presence of this custom attribute. Because this custom attribute will applied only to the LogOn action this will survive action and controller renames.

Comment: That sounds like a better idea! :-)

Comment: Nice, as dumb as it's going to sound is worth to comment this:
Not only you provided an elegant solution to authentication for both controller name and its index, you introduced the audience to the application start Application_Start method, which even though it is a basic, not everybody knows about it since the page cycle is a key point to distinct between ASP.NET WebForms and MVC so it is probably one of the last topics to check while you are learning. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would, as you suggested, move the Logon action to its own controller and apply the [Authorize] attribute to entire AdminController class.  This is cleaner and will be easier to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that you can do this with the `<location>` element in the web.config. Here's an example:

```
  <location path="/Admin/LogOn">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>  

  <location path="/Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: <location>-based authorization should *never* be used in an MVC application.  Remember: the resource you're trying to protect is the controller (or action), not the URL.  The MVC framework makes no guarantee that a URL starting with /Admin is the only way to hit AdminController.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

And inherit from that w/a naming convention:

```
public class UserAdminController : AdminController 
{
}
```

vs:

```
public class UserController : Controller 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Filter Providers.

[Phill Haack wrote about it here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx)

Comment: Read that too, but it felt more clunky than having a separate controller for the login :(