# Ninject Binding Attribute to Filter with Constructor Arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, attributes, filter, ninject

I read as many answers as I could for this, but they seem to fall short of one detail.

The trouble is when binding an action filter (with a service injected by controller) to a corresponding attribute, I've been unable to figure out how to pass parameter/property values from the attribute to its bound filter. Below is the code, and below that my intended fake-code:

**Filter & Attribute**

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
    private readonly UserRoles _requiredRoles;   // Enum

    public AuthorizationFilter(IAuthorizationService authorizationService, UserRoles requiredRoles)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
        _requiredRoles = requiredRoles;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session == null)
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        else {
            var authorized = _authorizationService.IsUserInRole((UserSessionInfoViewModel) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["user"], _requiredRoles);
            if (!authorized)
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            // else TODO: deal with cache... 
        }
    }
}

public class RequireRolesAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
    public readonly UserRoles RequiredRoles;

    public RequireRolesAttribute(UserRoles requiredRoles)
    {
        RequiredRoles = requiredRoles;
    }        
}
```

**Filter/Attribute Bindings**

```
kernel.BindFilter<AuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
      .WhenControllerHas<RequireRolesAttribute>();
kernel.BindFilter<AuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
      .WhenActionMethodHas<RequireRolesAttribute>();
```

This should make sure any controller/action decorated with [RolesRequired] is bound to the filter. So far so good. Now I want to declare via the attribute the roles (much like the stock AuthorizeAttribute) and pass those values onto the filter that actually does the authorization.

**Intended/Fake Code:**

```
[RequireRoles(UserRoles.Author)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // blah
}
```

**Specifically,**

What does it take to inform the AuthorizationFilter of the roles? Can the filter/ninject access the arguments passed to the attribute's constructor? Can the filter/ninject pull them from the attributes public property?

For reference, these articles were a huge help, but don't answer this one thing:

[Dependency Injection with Ninject and Filter attribute for asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc)

[Custom Authorization MVC 3 and Ninject IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572257/custom-authorization-mvc-3-and-ninject-ioc/5572752#5572752)

B Z, Remo Gloor, others... how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have figured it out (thanks to Remo's directions and documentation).

Use the appropriate **.WithConstructorArgument** extension whether you are binding to a Controller or Action filter. For example binding my action filter looks like this:

```
kernel.BindFilter<AuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
      .WhenActionMethodHas<RequireRolesAttribute>()
      .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<RequireRolesAttribute>("requiredRoles", o => o.RequiredRoles);
```

Once I understood the **Func<>** signature, it all became clear. The best way I found to handle this was to

1. make the extension type-specific for my attribute

   ```
   .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<TAttribute>()
   ```
2. fetch the value from the callback object (your attribute) via lambda:

   ```
   ("argumentName", o => o.PropertyName)
   ```

Comment: Any ideas as to what has to be done if the class deriving from `FilterAttribute` has constructor with multiple parameters (i.e. RequireRoles class in above example having constructor with multiple parametes) then how can the parameters be mapped in `.WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<TAttribute>()`  ??

Comment: To make the `BindFilter<>()` method available, you can add a reference to `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax`.

Answer (score 10):

and to bring the `BindFilter` extension method into scope don't forget to add;

```
using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be posted as a comment to the solution answer.