# WebApi Custom Filter with injected interface in constructor does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

My problem statement is same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc) i.e., use an injected service in attribute/filter. I have tried the solution given by B Z and following is my code along the lines of solution given.

```
//marker attribute
public class AuthorizeViewAttribute : Attribute { }

//filter
public class AuthorizeViewFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAccessRightsService _iAccessRightService;
    public AuthorizeViewFilter(IAccessRightsService iAccessRightService)
    {
        _iAccessRightService = iAccessRightService;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        RoleFeature roleFeature = _iAccessRightService.GetRoleFeatures();

        if (roleFeature.IsView)
        {
            //redirect to controller
        }
    }      
}
```

Following is the ninject binding I use:

```
this.BindFilter<AuthorizeViewFilter>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Controller, 0)
        .WhenControllerHas<AuthorizeViewAttribute>();
```

I do not need any parameter in attribute, so I figured I do not need to use WithConstructorArgument as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305476/ninject-binding-attribute-to-filter-with-constructor-arguments/8306795#8306795)

But my filter never gets called. I put a default constructor in AuthorizeViewAttribute , debugged and found that the control jumps to default constructor in AuthorizeViewAttribute and continues with the controller method.

I cannot find any solution to this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the startup code where you register the filter and/or filter provider with Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short story : You seem to be trying to use MVC filter and MVC binding on a webapi controller. That's why it does not work.

Long story : first create a webapi filter provider ( note, you will need [Ninject.Extensions.Factories](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) package to have `Func<AuthorizeViewFilter>` resolved by Ninject)

```
public class AuthorizeViewFilterProvider : System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly Func<AuthorizeViewFilter> _authorizeViewFilterFactory;

    public AuthorizeViewFilterProvider(Func<AuthorizeViewFilter> authorizeViewFilterFactory)
    {
        this._authorizeViewFilterFactory = authorizeViewFilterFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if(!actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeViewAttribute>().Any())
            return Enumerable.Empty<FilterInfo>();

        return new[]
        {
            new FilterInfo(this._authorizeViewFilterFactory(), FilterScope.Action)
        };
    }
}
```

then create a webapi filter

```
public class AuthorizeViewFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAccessRightsService _iAccessRightService;
    public AuthorizeViewFilter(IAccessRightsService iAccessRightService)
    {
        _iAccessRightService = iAccessRightService;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        RoleFeature roleFeature = _iAccessRightService.GetRoleFeatures();

        if (roleFeature.IsView)
        {
            return continuation();
        }
        else
          return Task.FromResult(actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Access denied"));
    }
}
```

then, bind the FilterProvider in your binding setup :

```
this.Bind<System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider>().To<AuthorizeViewFilterProvider>();
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! One follow up question: How would we pass attribute parameter to the filter?

Comment: As a follow up, I figured it out. We can use actionContext.actionDescriptor to get CustomAttribute and associated parameters.I also discovered this post which is pretty neat: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/