# Using Ninject in a Custom Authorize Attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm using Ninject to Inject my dependency in my Custom Authorize Attribute:

```
public class ValidatePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    [Inject]
    public IUsuarioRepository UsuarioRepository { get; set; }
}
```

My module:

```
this.BindFilter<ValidatePermissionAttribute>(FilterScope.Global, null);
```

I'm trying to search some documentation about my question, but I don't find.

My Question is about the second parameter in `BindFilter` method: `int? order`. What does this mean?

All example I see have a `0` with parameter (Like this question [Dependency Injection with Ninject and Filter attribute for asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc)). But in my case the injection of property only works with `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defines the order in which the filters are executed. Filters with smaller values are executed first.

See http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html about detailed information.