# Injecting dependencies into AuthorizeAttribute in a class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

I've run into an interesting design issue with a class library I am writing. I have a custom implementation of the AuthorizeAttribute that I want clients to be able to use like this:

```
[Protected("permission_name")]
```

In the above code, PermissionAttribute inherits from AuthorizeAttribute and uses a local default (DefaultContext created using HttpContext).

Behind the scenes, the attribute uses a SecurityService to check users, roles and permissions against (the SecurityService itself uses a client-provided persistence service that they can wire up in the composition root of their app).

So my attributes need a reference to the SecurityService to function. Since Attribute constructors can only have compile-time constants, I cannot use constructor injection.

I don't want to force my clients to use a DI framework - they should be able to *discover* and *wire up* the necessary dependencies in their composition root without using an IoC library, if they so choose.

Here are my options:

- Have the library use a singleton SecurityService.
- Use property injection, which would work but

  1. it would make the dependency seem optional, which it is not and
  2. I don't know where I can do property injection in an MVC app on an authorize attribute.

A possible solution to 2. above is to do set an instance of SecurityService as a static property on the attribute at application startup and use a guard clause to prevent it from being set more than once, like this:

```
class ProtectedAttribute : ...
{
    private static ISecurityService _SecurityService ;
    public static ISecurityService SecurityService
    {
        get 
        {
            return _SecurityService ;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (_SecurityService != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You can only set the SecurityService once per lifetime of this app.") ;
            _SecurityService = value ;
        }
    }
}
```

The SecurityService could be an abstract service facade so that it can be extended/replaced by a different implementation.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

UPDATE: Adding some code to show how I am going to do it:

Add a public property on the attribute that returns the permission name:

```
public class ProtectedAttribute : ...
{
  private string _Permission ;
  public string Permission { get { return _Permission ; } /*...*/ }

  public ProtectedAttribute(string permission) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Setup an authorization filter and configure dependency via Ninject (if using Ninject):

```
using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;

public class MyModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
  public override void Load()
  {
    // mySecurityService instance below can have a singleton lifetime - perfect!
    this.BindFilter<MyAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
        .WhenActionMethodHas<ProtectedAttribute>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("securityService", mySecurityService)
        .WithConstructorArgumentFromActionAttribute<ProtectedAttribute>("permission", p => p.PermissionName) ;
  }
}
```

Ohhh it's...beautiful *sniffle*

Comment: @Darin: Yes requiring a minimum of MVC 3 is acceptable. Updated the tags.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192543/injecting-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-3-action-filters-whats-wrong-with-this/7194467#7194467

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ASP.NET MVC 3 you could use constructor injection with action filters thanks to the new [IFilterProvider](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx). This way you no longer need to decorate your controller actions with action filters. You could apply them thanks to this interface and using a marker attribute.

And if you don't wanna bother implementing it manually you could always use an existing DI framework such as Ninject which provides a [fluent way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194159/29407) to define action filter dependencies.

Comment: +1 for `IFilterProvider` that gives quite clean solution. Similar problem [ASP.NET MVC IFilterProvider and separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708565/asp-net-mvc-ifilterprovider-and-separation-of-concerns) (Castle Windsor).

Answer (score 0):

My applications inherit from a base Application class that exposes the IOC container.

```
public interface IInjectableApplication
    {
        IUnityContainer Container { get; }
    }
```

Then I have a base attribute class, which is aware of this

```
public abstract IocAwareActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute{
    protected T ResolveItem<T>(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            var app = context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance as IInjectableApplication;
            if (app == null) { throw new NullReferenceException("Application is not IInjectable."); }

            T c = (T)app.Container.Resolve(typeof(T));

            if (c == null) { throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("Could not find injected {0}.", typeof(T).FullName)); }
            return c;
        }

}
```

While this is not true Injection, since Attributes aren't constructed 'normally', this provides a similar behavior. No reason it should not be adaptable to other IOCs