# C# AuthorizeAttribute InstancePerRequest Without Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, autofac, action-filter

I try to create new `AuthenticationAttribute` for per-request. I find a way with `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter` I can register in `WebApiConfig`, then I can use new instance for per request. However without autofac is there any way to do that.

```
public class AuthenticationAttribute : IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthService authService;

    public AuthenticationAttribute(IAuthService authService)
    {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    public  async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //some actionContext control with authService
    }
}
```

I need to do this because `IAuthService` is instance per-request. I'm using Autofac for DI but I don't want to use Autofac in my code directly like this.

Comment: I'm sure you've [read the docs, especially on how attributes are singletons and how to work around that?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filter-attributes-are-singletons)

Comment: Yes, I read it. Can we say AuthorizeAttribute is still singleton but  class from IAuthService created for per request

Comment: You have to use service location on `RequestServices` to get a per request thing like `IAuthService` in an attribute. No DI on attributes. The docs show an example of that.

Comment: You need to use a [custom IFilterProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10708565/) in order to resolve your `IAuthorizationFilter` per request. No service location is necessary at all.