# Action filter constructor being called repeatedly for single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using an action filter on some of my controllers, irrelevant what it does, that uses Ninject for dependency injection. I set breakpoints in the controller constructor and the action filter constructor, and I found that for a single request, the controller's constructor gets called once and the action filter's 8 times. The following code produces the effect, virtually the same as that given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194159).

Attribute:

```
public class NotificationAttribute : Attribute { }

public class NotificationActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public NotificationActionFilter(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _unitOfWork = uow;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Binding:

```
kernel.BindFilter<NotificationActionFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<NotificationAttribute>();
```

Controller:

```
[NotificationAttribute]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It's always exactly 8, but I have no idea why. I've really been pulling my hair out over this one, just hoping someone might have dealt with something similar before.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the `OnActionExecuting` method of your action filter how many times it gets hit?

Comment: Where is your kernel.BindFilter?

Comment: @parKing In NinjectWebCommon under App_Start, with all the rest of my bindings.

Comment: Can you confirm that none of the other bindings in the App_Start are displaying similar behavior?

Comment: @parKing They are not, but this is the only filter being bound, all the rest are just normal bindings.