# Custom filter attributes inject dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I'musing ASP.NET Web API and I need to have authorization so I've created custom authorization attribute

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

In order to inject dependency inside constructor I have following :

```
        public CustomAuthorizationAttribute(IAccountBL accountBl)
    {
        _accountBL = accountBl;
    }
```

In `IAccountBL` I have method which interacts with database checking if user is authorized to make request. 
Inside Member API controller I've register that attribute

```
    [CustomAuthorization]
public class MemberController : ApiController
```

But I get following error

> Project.Account.AccountBL' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

And if I register it like

```
[CustomAuthorization(IAccountBL)]
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone finds similar issue here's how I manage to solve it.

My custom filter inherits `IAutofacAuthorizationFilter`. Besides this one you can also inherit `IAutofacExceptionFilter` and `IAutofacActionFilter`.
And inside my DI container I've register this filter for each controller I want to use like this

```
        builder.Register(c => new CustomAuthorizationAttribute(c.Resolve<IAccountBL>()))
               .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<MemberController>()
               .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Answer (score 12):

Action filters are just attributes. You do not have control over when those attributes are instantiated by the CLR. One possibility is to write a marker attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute { }
```

and then the actual action filter:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAccountBL accountBL;
    public CustomAuthorizationFilter(IAccountBL accountBL)
    {
        this.accountBL = accountBL;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAuthorizationAttribute>().Any() || 
            actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<CustomAuthorizationAttribute>().Any())
        {
            // here you know that the controller or action is decorated 
            // with the marker attribute so that you could put your code
        }
    }
}
```

and finally register it as a global action filter:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        IAccountBL accountBL = ...
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(accountBL));
    }
}
```

and finally you could use the marker attribute:

```
[CustomAuthorization]
public class MemberController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, can u please explain me this part 
`IAccountBL accountBL = ...` because I'm injecting dependency into AccountBL also? How does initialization goes?

Comment: You could retrieve it from your DI container.

Comment: I've just started with DI and this is whole new world for me. Can u please help me, how do I retrieve it from DI container? I have AutoFacDependencyResolver class where I do registering modules, filters and controllers.

Comment: What did you do with the IAccountBL accountBL = ... part?

Answer (score 8):

You can get dependency in your filter by using extension method `GetDependencyScope` for class `HttpRequestMessage`. It's not a canonical way for dependency injection, but can be used as workaround. A basic example may look like this:

```
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dependencyScope = context.Request.GetDependencyScope();
        var dependency = dependencyScope.GetService(typeof (MyDependencyType));
        //use your dependency here
    }
```

This method may be used with constructor injection to simplify unit testing:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private Func<HttpRequestMessage, MyDependencyType> _dependencyFactory;

    public MyAuthenticationFilter() :
        this(request => (MyDependencyType)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(MyDependencyType)))
    {
    }

    public MyAuthenticationFilter(Func<HttpRequestMessage, MyDependencyType> dependencyFactory)
    {
        _dependencyFactory = dependencyFactory;
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var dependencyScope = context.Request.GetDependencyScope();
        var dependency = dependencyFactory.Invoke(context.Request);
        //use your dependency here
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you registered your service on the application using any container, it's very easy to get the instance of your service from anywhere in the scope. Just follow the below code to get your service.

`var myService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as IMyService;`

Please make sure you have included `System.Web.Mvc` in the file.

Happy coding!!!