# Injecting request scope objects to filters using ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I'm using Ninject latest dlls with ASP.NET MVC 4. I guess filters are created only once in the application and how can i inject a db helper class that has a life of request to a filter? Is this really possible? The db-helper class is disposed at the end of the request and because of that the connection object inside it will become null and I can't reuse it again in further requests. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency Injection with Ninject and Filter attribute for asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Darin I don't see how it's a duplicate. I'm not asking about how to inject dependencies to filters and I know that. I'm asking how to tackle injecting request scope objects (like dbcontext) to filter. In my case the dbhelper has connection object which becomes null and in the second request this throws exception. If filters are created in every request then it's fine but it's not the case.

Comment: Oh I see. I misread your question. Filters are not created for each request, so you cannot inject objects with per-request lifetime in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject a [factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) and use it to get an instance when evaluating the filter.

Comment: Thanks Remo. I'm looking for something like that.