# BindFilter does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

Where is `BindFilter`?
Cannot install  `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax`;
I need this for `ActionFilterAttribute` cannot inject constructor argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Ninject and MVC3 Dependency injection action filter on Controller and Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881026/problem-with-ninject-and-mvc3-dependency-injection-action-filter-on-controller-a)

Comment: i have Ninject 3.3.4